# get a user's token authenticated by facebook with auth0

Tags: facebook, auth0, bearer-token

I would like to send requests to my backend with the token that is received on my frontend when I authenticate using Auth0 with the provider Facebook, but I would like to do this using Postman instead of having to run my frontend.

The reason for this is that I don't have to open my frontend every time I want to get the access token of the user who authenticated through the Facebook Provider, I would like to obtain this token through Postman and send requests with the Authorization header.

I'm a little lost in the Auth0 documentation when it comes to authenticating with Facebook through Postman, as I would like to get the Bearer type token to insert in my request headers for my backend.

I've been reading this [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/identity-provider-access-tokens) but I don't know if I'm sure this is what I really need.

**How can I get a user's token that has been authenticated by Facebook on Postman?**

> The reason for this is that my application will only accept
> authentication via Facebook.

Comment: Not really clear to me, what you are asking here. Getting a user access token, requires user interaction - usually in a web browser. They are logged into Facebook in there. Not sure where/how you want Postman to come into play now?

Comment: I need to test my backend, but I always have to authenticate through the frontend and get this token generated when I authenticate on Facebook to make the calls, I would like to get this token to make my calls without having to authenticate through my frontend, and I need a token of a user that was registered with the provider facebook for my tests.

Comment: _“I would like to get this token to make my calls without having to authenticate through my frontend”_ - that is not possible. Extend the user access token you got the “normal” way, then it is valid for up to 60 days, that should give you ample time for testing.